# HTML for topic Tour and Travel

Tags: html

Robert has created a user-defined function to ensure that the form fields are not left blank while
submitting the form. This is a time-consuming task. Help Robert to identify the form attribute that
he can use to ensure that the form fields are not left blank

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Robert needs to do his own homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Robert is working in HTML5, Robert can use the `required` attribute(for input fields) instead of writing separate user-defined function for blank fields.

Usage of the same

```
Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

I hope this is helpful to Robert!! 
There are also a variety of third party plugins to ensure the same. Robert should consider those options too!!